# Python correct way to assign variables to MYSQL query?

Tags: python, mysql

What are different ways to reference a Python variable into MySQL statement?

I know you can reference like this:

```
var = "String"

cursor.execute("select * from table where column1 = %s") % (var)
```

I saw somebody mention to use `?`. What are other ways to do it?

Comment: Your statement above is totally incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by passing parameters:

```
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO Employee
                       (id, Name, Joining_date, salary) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"""

insert_tuple_1 = (1, "Json", "2019-03-23", 9000)
cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, insert_tuple_1)
connection.commit()
```

Example taken from [here](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/)